# How do i copy or manage multiple grafana instances on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana, prometheus-operator

I'm trying to copy some grafana dashboards between multiple kubernetes environments (dev, test, prod...). In order to do it, i was trying to practice this with an instance of grafana from the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack).

For my first approach i startet two kubernetes cluster using

```
$ helm install project1 prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
$ helm install project2 prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
```

to copy one grafana dashboard to another kubernetes cluster.
However, this "simple" task already overtaxed me.

After some research, i found proposals to create configmaps to copy those grafana dashboards, but i couldn't figure out to do it so far :(

Another solution i often stumbled across was the [grafana wizzy](https://github.com/grafana-wizzy/wizzy) repo, which was unfortunately archived and stopped maintainance several years ago. I think this sounds exactly like the tool i was looking for.

And now i am looking for an alternative way to easily manage or copy grafana entities.

Comment: The github repository for kube-prometheus-stack has its default dashboards as ConfigMap, have you tried to do something similar? Looks like applying some label to those objects would be enough to have them added to Grafana.

Comment: I'm looking for something more comfortable than copying hundreds of ConfigMaps :D

Comment: @SYN can you tell me how to use these Configmaps? Do i save my dashboards as JSON and import them as data source in my Configmap?

Comment: Having some json file, something like: `kubectl create cm -n project1 my-dashboard-name --from-file=Dashboard.json=./my-dashboard-source-file.json`, then `kubectl label cm -n project1 my-dashboard-name grafana_dashboard=1`